# How do I limit the characters pulled from getBody in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to pull data from gmail (ie. from, to, date, subject, body, etc.) but I'm getting an error saying the getBody() length is too long:

> your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell

I'm trying to have a cut off of characters or just not pull the email with a Body over the character limit. Also, I'm pretty out of practice on this and it's not working...

```
//Allow user to select label(s) and date range
function getGmailEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var label = sheet.getRange(1, 3).getValue();
  var after = sheet.getRange(2, 3).getDisplayValue();
  var before = sheet.getRange(3, 3).getDisplayValue();
  var threads = GmailApp.search("label:" + label + " AND " + "after:" + after + " AND " + "before:" + before);

  // Export emails into table of values in google sheet
  // Character length cutoff is 2000, the cell with get Body would tell you to go to the inbox
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length < 2000; i++) {
    var temp = [];
    var label = threads[i].getLabels().map(e => e.getName()).join(", ");
    let messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      temp.push([
        label,
        messages[j].getFrom(),
        messages[j].getTo(),
        messages[j].getCc(),
        messages[j].getDate(),
        messages[j].getSubject(),
        messages[j].getBody(),
        messages[0].getId()
      ]);
    }
    values = values.concat(temp);
  }
  sheet.getRange(6, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Please add the textual error message.

Comment: your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is by using `String.prototype.slice()`.

Replace

```
messages[j].getBody(),
```

by

```
messages[j].getBody().slice(0,50000),
```

Related

- [Substring vs Slice vs Other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57130961/1595451)

Comment: is there any difference between using substring or slice for this? just curious.

Comment: @AllisterLobo See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice